# react tips not appearing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip

I am working on a component right now that is a mapped stack of divs. Each one should have a tooltip but for the life of me I can't get the tooltip to appear

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            options: [
                {
                    id: '1',
                    label: 'Industrial Truck and Tractor Operators',
                    value: '53-7051',
                    tooltip_text: 'Operate industrial trucks or tractors equipped to move materials around a warehouse, storage yard, factory, construction site, or similar location. Excludes “Logging Equipment Operators" (45-4022).',
                },
                {
                    id: '2',
                    label: 'Order Clerks',
                    value: '43-4151',
                    tooltip_text: 'Receive and process incoming orders for materials, merchandise, classified ads, or services such as repairs, installations, or rental of facilities. Generally receives orders via mail, phone, fax, or other electronic means. Duties include informing customers of receipt, prices, shipping dates, and delays; preparing contracts; and handling complaints. Excludes "Dispatchers, Except Police, Fire, and Ambulance" (43-5032) who both dispatch and take orders for services.',
                },
            ],
            value: null,
            className: '',
            selectedClassName: '',
            loading_State: true, loads
            childrenCount: 0
        };
        this.setProps = this.setProps.bind(this);
    }

    setProps(newProps) { //this is going to update the state
        this.setState(newProps);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DashControlledContainer

                    setProps={this.setProps}
                    options = {this.state.options}
                    value = {this.state.value}
                    styles = {this.state.styles}
                    className = {this.state.className}
                    selectedClassName = {this.state.selectedClassName}
                    loading_State = {this.state.loading_State}
                    childrenCount = {this.state.childrenCount}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;





//the component being returned with the tooltip

render(){


  return (
            <div style={this.props.styles}>
                {this.props.options.map(option => (
                <div key = {option} id={option.id} style={option.style}

                  onClick = {e=>{ //updates the props with the clicked targets value if setProps is accessible
                    if(this.props.setProps){
                      this.props.setProps({value: e.target.value})
                    }else{
                      this.setState({value:e.target.value})
                    }
                  }}
                >

                    <span  id={option.id}> {option.label} </span>
                    <UncontrolledTooltip placement="right" target={option}>
                            {option.tooltip_text}
                    </UncontrolledTooltip>

                </div>

                ))}
            </div>
        );
}
```

I'm not sure where to set my target for the tooltip maybe thats the issue? I haven't been able to find many resources online. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code for ```UncontrolledTooltip```? Are you using a library? Can't tell what the problem is without seeing how it works.

Comment: Hi monsterpiece, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should provide `id` as a target to your `UncontrolledTooltip`,

```
<UncontrolledTooltip placement="right" target={option.id}> //set id of span as a target here
    hello
</UncontrolledTooltip>
```

Comment: upon trying this I get: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '1' is not a valid selector.  I have updated the code to show my current state that I am passing as a prop to the app. the option array in my state has within it an object   id: '1' I'm not sure why I can't select this as the ID?

Comment: I think the issue is here `const {id, options, style, setProps, loading_State} = this.props;` when you try to destructure the props, I can see your state don't have `id` and `style`. So it might be that issue. Suggest you to not pass complete state as `{...this.state}`, you need to pass the specific state individually.

Comment: thanks for your advice. unfortunately after trying this it still gives me the error I mentioned previously.     SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '1' is not a valid selector

Comment: Something interesting that I notice is that by changing state.options.id to an int instead of a string I don't get any errors but there's still no tooltip showing

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out, including a string in my id fixed it for some reason?

i made my div contain id={"option"+option.id}

```
then I referenced it like so:

<UncontrolledTooltip placement="right" target={"option"+option.id}>
         {option.tooltip_text}
  </UncontrolledTooltip>
```